# Logistic Regression with GLM

Tags: regression, julia, glm

I was trying to bring some of my R Code to Julia, but have a problem with the GLM Package. The dataset is grouped by age and in each group are m_i individuals from which N_i are sick. I want to estimate the probability of being sick as a function of age - a typical logistic regression problem. I R the code would look like:

```
fit <- glm(cbind(N, m - N) ~ age, family = binomial, data = heart)
```

I tried in Julia the following function call, but it does not work:

```
glm(@formula((N, m-N) ~ age), df, Binomial(), LogitLink())
```

Any ideas? The dataset could be found here: http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/heart.dat

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to construct a binary variable `sick` that corresponds to number of sick and not sick observations in each age group. I achieve this below by creating a separate `DataFrame` for each age group and then running `vcat` on them.

Here is the code that does the job assuming that you read in your data in `heart` data frame (I squashed creation of `heart_flat` into one line, but you can extract the comprehension inside to see what is created on the go):

```
heart_flat = vcat([DataFrame(age=row[:age],
                             sick=[ones(Int, row[:N]);
                                   zeros(Int, row[:m]-row[:N])])
                   for row in eachrow(heart)]...)

glm(@formula(sick ~ age), heart_flat, Binomial(), LogitLink())
```

It produces the same estimates as those in R.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. But what do you mean with "but you can extract the comprehension inside to see what is created on the go". Where would I have to put them?

Comment: If you run `[DataFrame(age=row[:age],
                             sick=[ones(Int, row[:N]);
                                   zeros(Int, row[:m]-row[:N])])
                   for row in eachrow(heart)]` in REPL you can see the individual `DataFrames` on which `vcat` is applied.